# JPA - SELECT entity FROM a subset

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I've got an Entity class named Fee. After performing an initial query, if more than one Fee is returned, I'd like to add some (WHERE) conditions only on the rows returned by the first query. Since a code snippet is better than a thousand words, here it is:

```
// Results of initial query
List<Fee> fees = queryFindFees.getResultList();
if (fees == null || fees.size() <= 0)
    return null;
if (fees.size() == 1) {
    Fee f = fees.get(0);
    jpa.refresh(f);
    return f;
}

// More than one fee found
String sqlBase = "SELECT f FROM Fee f WHERE f IN :fees";
String sqlComplete = sqlBase/* + " AND f.isValid = ?1"*/;
queryFindFees = jpa.createQuery(sqlComplete);
queryFindFees.setParameter("fees", fees);
// Commented out for test
// queryFindFees.setParameter(1, "Y");
List<Fee> specFees = queryFindFees.getResultList();
```

Now, since I'm actually asking for the EntityManager to return all the Fees already returned in the previous query, I would expect the same resultset. Instead the list specFees is always empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Luca

EDIT 1: Details of Entity class Fee

```
@Entity
public class Fee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 1)
    private String isValid;

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object arg0) {
        if (!(arg0 instanceof Fee))
            return false;
        Fee f0 = (Fee) arg0;
        return f0.getId() == this.getId();
    }
}
```

The generated SQL (sqlComplete variable) is as expected:

```
SELECT f FROM Fee f WHERE f IN :fees
```

EDIT 2: As suggested by Deepak, using the collection of IDs works:

```
String sqlBase = "SELECT f FROM Fee f WHERE f.id IN :feesIds";
String sqlComplete = sqlBase/* + " AND f.isValid = ?1"*/;
List<Long> feesIds = new ArrayList<Long>();
for (Fee f : fees) {
    feesIds.add(f.getId());
}
queryFindFees = jpa.createQuery(sqlComplete);
queryFindFees.setParameter("feesIds", feesIds);
```

Using this code the query works (returns all the original Fees), however if possible I would like to avoid using the for cycle because the number of Fee instances may be very large...

Comment: I guess, in clause should be with parentheses as "SELECT f FROM Fee f WHERE f IN (:fees)";

Comment: @Gayathri Thanks, but I believe it depends on the JPA implementation and version, in mine (EclipseLink 2.5) it's correct without brackets (I also tried to add them and I get a syntax error).

Comment: Indeed, in some cases the brackets are needed. Thanks again.

Comment: I haven't worked with eclipse link.

Comment: What is the SQL generated?  Is it what you expect, and do the entities returned initially all have the isValid flag set to "Y"?

Comment: Does `Fee` have a simple or compound key? I might help to share the relevant parts of the entity class. Also, as Chris said, taking a look at the generated SQL is probably a good start.

Comment: @Chris The generated SQL is the same as the base SQL (as you can see from the code I commented out the isValid clause in order to exclude any possible problem).

Comment: @DannyMo Fee has a simple primary key (identity)

Comment: @Luc have you overrided equals() method in the Fee class ??

Comment: @Luc  Alternatively you can also use `SELECT f FROM Fee f WHERE f.id IN :fees` this time your fees parameter will contain `list of ids` of `Fee objects`

Comment: @Deepak I edited the question and added the overridden equals method.

Comment: @Luc `return f0.getId() == this.getId();` replace this with `return f0.getId().equals(this.getId();` run and see

Comment: @Deepak Can't do it since id is a long primitive value. However the other method you suggested worked, I'm editing the question now.

Comment: @Luc  Make it Long in your Fee class the problem is with your equals method since == compare the instances not the values hence jpa is not loading your instances because it internally using equals method .I am giving the answer Please accept it

Comment: @Deepak Changed the id to Long instead of long and used `return f0.getId().equals(this.getId());` within equals method, but it doesn't work. However I can accept the other solution you gave (cycling through ids) if you repost it as an answer.

Comment: @luc you used createQuery which takes JPQL and converts it to SQL.  Turn on logging to finest and parameter logging on to see if the SQL and parameters are the same as when you pass in a list of IDs instead of entities.  Also post the version of eclipselink and try the latest if you aren't already - I seem to believe there might have been issues fixed like this with entities in collection parameters, but I don't remember details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your overridden equals method is creating problem .Make your id Long Object and use the below overridden method .Alternatively u can use this query also

```
SELECT f FROM Fee f WHERE f.id IN :fees
```

this time your fees parameter will contain list   of ids of `Fee objects`

```
@Entity
public class Fee implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(nullable = false, length = 1)
private String isValid;

...

 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object arg0) {
    if (!(arg0 instanceof Fee))
        return false;
    Fee f0 = (Fee) arg0;
    return f0.getId().equals(this.getId());
  }
}
```

Comment: @Luc reported the other answer also

Comment: As said before, converting the id field from long to Long and using equals doesn't work.
The solution using the alternative query `SELECT f FROM Fee f WHERE f.id IN :feesIds` and passing a List<Long> as parameter works fine, but it's not the solution to the original problem (it's more of a workaround).

Comment: However accepted as answer since no other solution seems to work.

Comment: @Luc i am installing ecclipse link and JPA to look in to the original problem